# Derivative of a Function with a Matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, lagrange-multiplier

I honestly cannot find something similar to this function online - every other case I have found (and which seems to be very standard) is $x^T$Ax.

A question my professor asked involved finding the derivative of f($\mathbf x$) = A($\mathbf x$)$\bullet$$\mathbf x$, f: $ℝ^n$ -> ℝ.

For context: he wants us to use Lagrange multipliers to show that if $\mathbf x$ is a local extremum of f subject to constraint ||$\mathbf x$|| = 1, then there exists $\lambda \in$ ℝ s.t. A$\mathbf x$ = $\lambda$$\mathbf x$

I want to give an honest try at the proof before I ask anyone for help, so I just provided it for context in case it makes a difference. I just can't for the life of me figure out the basic derivative! My gut is saying that it's a simple product rule application, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Try to write it out each component of the matrix vector product and take derivatives. Then write that as a matrix vector product again

Comment: Isn't $A(x)\bullet x = x^T A x$?

Comment: @user251257 yeah after some tinkering i got there haha, i had never seen that explicitly defined so it took a bit of writing stuff out to find that